# WP8 Get User's Lockscreen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to get current device lock screen in WIndows Phone 8 ?
I didn't find a way to make a transparent app so I want to get the lock screen and used it as background.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? Your question sounds as if you're trying to capture someone's password, while he/she thinks its the real lockscreen

Comment: No, actually I want to make my app with transparent background - but I didn't find a way to do that. So I am trying to get Lock Screen background and use to look like a transparent app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no ways of **getting** the lock screen background, but there are ways of [setting it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206968(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but I am really trying to **get** it. Or to make my root view's background transparent...

Comment: No matter how hard you try, it's not possible. ;)